# correct usage of html button text in regards to accessibility

Tags: html, accessibility, uiaccessibility

I have a form with 3 input fields and then a button that is shaped like a next symbol.

When you click on the next symbol the 3 input fields disappear and new inputs fields will show up and also a submit button.

code:

```
<div class="col-md-1" id="next_area">
   <button type="button" class="glyphicon"></button>
   <div id="text1">Next</div>
</div>
```

I want the "Next" text to appear below the button, hence a separated `<div>`. 
What's the correct way to set the text here? Since the button itself doesn't have a text, will it be clear that this button is required to click?

I checked, I could add these tag to `<button>`:

`data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#text1"`

But I didn't find them on this [page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques/Using_the_button_role)  so not sure if that make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should enclose all your elements within a button:

```
<div class="col-md-1" id="next_area">
   <button type="button">
      <div class="glyphicon"></div>
      <div id="text1">Next</div>
   </button>
</div>
```

This way the "Next" text will be clickable and the `button` will have a valid text replacement.

Then for styling purpose, you'll have to remove default button css properties:

```
button {
  border: 0;
  background:transparent;
}
```

You could also replace the `button` with a `<div tabindex="0" role="button">` element.

Note that within your example you could add `aria-describedby="text1"` to your `button` in order to satisfy screenreader users, but this wouldn't help standard users.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps you can use  instead of button

Like

```
<div class="button">
   <i class="glyphicon"></i>
   <div id="text1">Next</div>
</div>
```